# what's wrong with my sum if model code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I tried to return zero, I tested in mySql it work's
but when in codeIgniter model the code error, what's wrong with my code :

here is my code :

```
function getAnak()
    {
    $this->db->select('sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak')
    ->from('tbl_hub_kel');
    $this->db->join('tbl_hasil_sensus','tbl_hasil_sensus.id_keluarga = tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga','right');
    $this->db->where('tbl_hasil_sensus.is_new', 0);
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take care about counting the number of paranthesis over here

```
$this->db->select('sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak from tbl_hub_kel')
                      ^^
```

should be

```
$this->db->select('sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak )',false)
                     ^^                                                  ^^
```

Comment: now I tried like this : $this->db->select('sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak)',false);
 ->from('tbl_hub_kel');    and the message error : syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: It because you were appending your query after semicolon instead use it like as `$this->db->select('sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak')->from('tbl_hub_kel');`

Comment: when I delete the semicolon, still error like this : Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Comment: Try as `$q = $this->db->get()->result_array(); return $q; `

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the braces properly

```
sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0) as anak from tbl_hub_kel
```

Update this to

```
sum(if(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga = 4,1,0)) as anak from tbl_hub_kel
```